# Access denied when trying to write a file

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm trying to write a file but when I run the program it says access denied, I already tried checking the security proprietes and opening VS as admin but doens't work here's the funtion that builds the file

```
public void fazfich() {
    string createText = "\"" + this.Companhia + "\",\"" + this.NrFuncionario + "\",\"" + this.Nome1 + "\",\"" + this.Nome2 + "\",\"" + this.DtNascimento + "\",\"" + this.Sexo +
        "\",\"" + this.PIN + "\",\"" + this.EMAIL + "\",\"" + this.TpColaborador + "\",\"" + this.CodLingua + "\",\"" + this.CodLingualSO + "\",\"" + this.CodCentroCst +
        "\",\"" + this.CodEscala + "\",\"" + this.CodSector + "\",\"" + this.CodCentroTrb + "\",\"" + this.CodDirecao + "\",\"" + this.CodCategoria + "\",\"" + this.CodCompnhiaExt +
        "\",\"" + this.DsCompanhiaExt + "\",\"" + this.Telefone + "\",\"" + this.InfAutomaticas + "\",\"" + this.HorasExtra + "\",\"" + this.TpControlo +
        "\",\"" + this.CodGrpControlo + "\",\"" + this.NrFuncionarioAlt + "\",\"" + this.TpHorario + "\",\"" + this.TolAtrasoDia + "\",\"" + this.TolAtrasoPrd +
        "\",\"" + this.TolSaidaDia + "\",\"" + this.TolSaidaPrd + "\",\"" + this.SaldoDia + "\",\"" + this.SaldoPrd + "\",\"" + this.TemSaldo + "\",\"" + this.Sistema +
        "\",\"" + this.Saldo + "\",\"" + this.TemCredito + "\",\"" + this.PrecoRefeicao + "\",\"" + this.Subsidio + "\",\"" + this.NrRefeircoes + "\",\"" + this.TpPaga +
        "\",\"" + this.CodPaga + "\",\"" + this.Info + "\",\"" + this.Obs + "\",\"" + this.DtAdmissao + "\",\"" + this.DtDemissao + "\",\"" + this.SisLogico + "\",\"" +
        this.Cartao + "\",\"" + this.DtValidadeIni + "\",\"" + this.DtValidadeFim + "\",\"" + this.Versao + "\",\"" + this.NomeCartao + "\",\"" + this.CodGrpPermissao +
        "\",\"" + this.CodPerfil + "\",\"" + this.PINCARTAO + "\",\"" + this.Status + "\",\"" + this.Info1 + "\",\"" + this.Info2 + "\",\"" + this.Info3 + "\",\"" +
        this.Info4 + "\",\"" + this.Info5 + "\",\"" + this.Info6 + "\",\"" + this.Info7 + "\",\"" + this.Info8 + "\",\"" + this.Info9 + "\",\"" + this.Info10 + "\",\"" +
        this.Msg1 + "\",\"" + this.Msg2 + "\",\"" + this.Provisorio + "\",\"" + this.IDAplicaçã o + "\",\"" + this.AgrpSalarios + "\",\"" + this.Visitante + "\",\"" +
        this.Empresa + "\"\r\n";
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ec2ac9097\Documents\estagio\WebApplicationAPI", createText);
}
```

the program is a Web API

Comment: formatting fix + delete unrelated tag

Answer (score 0):

The API will run under some specific user, which you can check under the IIS setup. That particular user won't have the right to create something in a user folder like where you're trying to write the file.

You can verify this by trying to write somewhere else where IIS has full access like inetpub or maybe your temp folder.

Definitely do not test this with IIS Express, set it up in IIS from the very beginning. In the end you'll have to setup specific users with specific rights if you want to create files on disk.